# dynamic hidden, visible div event on jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm implementing vote system.

When mouse over on main image, image will be grayed out, and then rating ui will be visible.
Then users click rating by 1 to 5 value.

I wanna show when users trying to click rate, rating div(like a star) visible and hidden.
I made hidden event on div dynamically. But once div hidden, they can't take mouseover event I think. What should I do ?

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".innerDiv").hide();
     //$(".rating").hide();
     
     $("#wrapperDiv").on({
      mouseover: function() {
       $(".innerDiv").show();
      }, mouseout: function() {
       $(".innerDiv").hide();
      }
     });
     
     $(".rating").on({
      mouseover: function() {
       var index = $(this).attr("value");
       
       var i = 0;
       for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
     if(i<index) {
         $($(".rating")[i]).css('visibility', 'visible')
     } else {
         $($(".rating")[i]).css('visibility', 'hidden')
     }        
       }       
      }, click: function() {
       alert('you voted rate ' + $(this).attr("value") + '!');
      }
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapperDiv" style="cursor:pointer;width:200px;height:350px;border:1px solid;background:green;">
  <div class="innerDiv" id="topInnerDiv" style="width:200px;height:20px;border:1px solid;background:yellow;">
   <span>Main Topic Image</span>
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv" id="mainInnerDiv" style="width:200px;height:210px;border:1px solid;background:green;">
   <span>Grayed out Topic Image</span>
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv" id="midInnerDiv" style="width:200px;height:20px;border:1px solid;background:blue;">
   <span>rating by star</span>
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv" id="bottomInnerDiv" style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid;background:red;">
   <div class="rating" value="1" id="rating1" style="border:0px;float:left;width:30px;height:50px;background:blue">
    <span>1</span>
   </div>
   <div class="rating" value="2" id="rating2" style="border:0px;float:left;width:30px;height:50px;background:black">
    <span>2</span>
   </div>
   <div class="rating" value="3" id="rating3" style="border:0px;float:left;width:30px;height:50px;background:pink">
    <span>3</span>
   </div>
   <div class="rating" value="4" id="rating4" style="border:0px;float:left;width:30px;height:50px;background:purple">
    <span>4</span>
   </div>
   <div class="rating" value="5" id="rating5" style="border:0px;float:left;width:30px;height:50px;background:white">
    <span>5</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fadeTo` method of jQuery instead of using `visibility` property. Because `mouseover` event will not trigger for hidden elements.

But this `fadeTo` method will changes the `opacity` of the`div` for showing and hiding it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".innerDiv").hide();
            //$(".rating").hide();

            $("#wrapperDiv").on({
                mouseover: function () {
                    $(".innerDiv").show();
                    $(".rating").show();
                }, mouseout: function () {
                    $(".innerDiv").hide();
                }
            });

            $(".rating").on({
                mouseover: function () {
                    var index = $(this).attr("value");

                    var i = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        if (i < index) {
                            $($(".rating")[i]).fadeTo(1, 1);
                        } else {
                            $($(".rating")[i]).fadeTo(1,0);
                        }
                    }
                }, click: function () {
                    alert('you voted rate ' + $(this).attr("value") + '!');
                }
            });            
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapperDiv" style="cursor:pointer;width:200px;height:350px;border:1px solid;background:green;">
        <div class="innerDiv" id="topInnerDiv" style="width:200px;height:20px;border:1px solid;background:yellow;">
            <span>Main Topic Image</span>
        </div>
        <div class="innerDiv" id="mainInnerDiv" style="width:200px;height:210px;border:1px solid;background:green;">
            <span>Grayed out Topic Image</span>
        </div>
        <div class="innerDiv" id="midInnerDiv" style="width:200px;height:20px;border:1px solid;background:blue;">
            <span>rating by star</span>
        </div>
        <div class="innerDiv" id="bottomInnerDiv" style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid;background:red;">
            <div class="rating" value="1" id="rating1" style="border:0px;float:left;width:30px;height:50px;background:blue">
                <span>1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rating" value="2" id="rating2" style="border:0px;float:left;width:30px;height:50px;background:black">
                <span>2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rating" value="3" id="rating3" style="border:0px;float:left;width:30px;height:50px;background:pink">
                <span>3</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rating" value="4" id="rating4" style="border:0px;float:left;width:30px;height:50px;background:purple">
                <span>4</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rating" value="5" id="rating5" style="border:0px;float:left;width:30px;height:50px;background:white">
                <span>5</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope this helps you !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `opacity: 0` and `opacity: 1` to change the visibility. When something is `opacity: 0`, it can still trigger mouseover events.